Cumulative Addition of Index Switch Node Values

In the above node setup, there is a value corresponding to every instance index in the Value node. The other Index Switch - Cumulative Value is the cumulative addition of all the values up to but excepting the current index.
Right now, I am populating the values manually in both the nodes. The values in Value node will have to be entered manually anyway, as they are static values corresponding to each instance. I was wondering if there is anyway we can calculate the cumulative addition values dynamically, so that every time there is a change in the first set, I don't need to change the other one.

(Using Blender 4.2.0)
You can combine a Points node and an Accumulate Field node to build a lookup table because the Cumulative Value you are looking for is actually the Trailing output by this last node (see dark pink nodes in the following graph). Then to query the table, use a Sample Index node (see dark blue nodes in the following graph). To my knowledge, there is not way to compute how many Item Inputs there are in an Index Switch node. So this Count has to be specified manually also (set to 5 in the following demonstration).


You can optimize by using a "Capture Attribute", so the accumulation doesn't need to happen on every separate field (not sure if it's not optimized internally but probably not). As for figuring out the number of options automatically, I tried making a driver to node's dimensions[1] but unfortunately it showed as 0... A Python driver would work with len(inputs)-1
